# how to solve the middle block problem(consider edge blocks and leave any block in the middle of row)

Tags: c++, algorithm, visual-c++

I need to solve this algorithm problem. In the diagram, there are many rows with different no. of blocks. Each block is either good or bad. The block with no. 1 on it is good block and rest are all bad. I need to do the grouping of these blocks  in 2 in order to find whether the resultant of these groupings is good or bad. If I make a group of 2 , I will check if all the blocks are having '1' on it. If yes, then the resultant block is good, otherwise bad.

Problem: while doing groupings of blocks, I always have to consider the blocks that are on the edges. If the row has odd number of blocks(lets say 9) and I'm making group of 2, then the middle block(5th block) has to be ignored, the blocks on the edges should get preference with respect to middle block. I don't know how to solve the problem as I'm confused with the part of ignoring the middle block in case of odd no. of blocks.It can ignore any block(near to middle block) but have to consider the blocks on the edges.

So basically, First I need to find if the row has odd/even no.of blocks according to the groupsize which is 2. Then if odd no. of blocks are here, leave the middle one and make a group with blocks on edges and find the result if the resultant is good or bad.

In the inputs, I have the X and Y co-ordinate of each and every block and its information as the block is good or bad.

[image]

Comment: What was the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: I/m getting difficulity in starting doing the problem. I don't know, How to consider the blocks on the edges and leave the middle one in case of odd number of blocks. How do I start it?

Comment: How do you store the rows in memory?

Comment: In the input, I have the x and y co-ordinate of each block. I can use the matrix form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like throwing away the exact middle block isn't a good solution.  With a row of size 7, you should be able to make 3 pairs, but if you discard the center one, you'll only get two pairs usable.

Try taking blocks from both ends alternately: A pair from the left, then a pair from the right, then the next pair inward from the left.  When your two pointers (or indexes) cross in the middle, you're done with the row.  When necessary you'll discard a block as near to the middle as possible, and you won't need any special case for even vs odd.

Comment: Yes, It can be any block except the blocks on the edges.

Comment: I can't use pointers as I need to do it without pointers using VB. Any simple way to do it?

Comment: your solution is right but I need to implement in VB language. That is, without pointers

Comment: @user: Use the array offset.  But if you need to use VB, why did you tag the question as `c++` `visual-c++`?

Comment: I thought i can get an idea and write my code in vb. If I can get code in c++, i can convert in VB .That's the only reason. Moreover, c/c++ guys are quick and reply fast

Comment: Array offset is in C#. Do you have nay better idea to do it?

Comment: @user: VB also has array offset (index).